# How to define encoding (eg UTF-16) when converting char[] to byte[]?

Tags: java, encoding, char, byte, utf

I got the following code, which converts a char[] to a byte[]:

```
char[] cPwd = {'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd'};
byte[] bPwd = new byte[cPwd.length * 2];
ByteBuffer.wrap(bPwd).asCharBuffer().put(cPwd);
```

What I guessing is that the code above would use the default platform encoding (UTF-8 or 16, i suppose). Right?

How would I make sure the chars from the char[] above use a specific encoding, say UTF-16, as opposed to relying on the default platform encoding?

ps - There is a constraintin my scenario: I am NOT ALLOWED to convert this char[] to a string like in

```
String str = new String(cPwd, "UTF-16");
```

Thank you in advance.

Alex.

Comment: *"I am NOT ALLOWED to convert this char[] to a string like in ..."* - so is this homework?

Comment: Although it smells like homework, in handling passwords, it is common practice to avoid creating a String object because Strings are immutable (whereas you can zero out the char buffer after use and thus try to avoid the unencrypted password 'knocking about' accidentally in memory).

Comment: Although my wording does sound like homework, it's not. lol

Comment: So why are you "NOT ALLOWED" to use the obvious solution?

Comment: I actually have a bigger problem, which I state here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973707/where-will-utf-16-or-any-other-encoding-fit-in-my-code
But I think because the post is too big, nobody has replied yet. So I decided to ask something else in a shorter way but unfortunately it looks like a homework question.
So yeah, if wanna (can) have a go at the post, please don't hesitate.

And yeah, my question was based on the idea @NeilCoffey described above.

Comment: @StephenC well, I'm not a native english speaker unfortunately :( Perhaps a better way of wording it would be "because char[] passwords are not meant to be converted to strings so they don't end up hanging around in memory until the garbage collector gets rid of them, I do not want to convert the char[] to a string" or something of that sort.

Does that sound less "homework"?! :)

Comment: @Alex - I see.  I'm convinced that passwords in unreachable strings is a serious security concern though.  If you have enough control of the JVM / OS to fish a password out of (say) a heap dump, you can get it other ways too.  (Yea ... I know some security folks would disagree.)

Comment: @StephenC - I would definitely agree that the system isn't infallible in all scenarios (hence I was careful to say "*try* to avoid"). But it can give you more of a chance of protecting the password where User A enters their password in a non-doctored environment (neither code nor JVM doctored/running in debug mode etc, no keylogger-- i.e. probably 'their machine'), then User B comes along afterwards and tries to examine a memory dump to retrieve the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time the VM sees them, the chars that you specify as literals in your code will be 16-bit Unicode characters. The asCharBuffer() method isn't specified as performing any encoding. In other words, you should effectively get UTF-16, either little or big endian depending on the endianness of your ByteBuffer.

If you want another encoding without going via the String constructor, you can use the CharSet.encode() method:

```
        CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.wrap(your chars);
        Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        ByteBuffer bb = cs.encode(cb);
```

Comment: That was just what I was after. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I hope that you understand that is pretty much the same as what `String.getBytes()` is doing under the covers ...

Comment: It is-- just that in this case we don't have a String to call getBytes() on for reasons above... :)

Answer (score 1):

> What I guessing is that the code above would use the default platform encoding (UTF-8 or 16, i suppose). Right?

I don't think so.  If my understanding of the javadoc is correct, the `asCharBuffer()` method returns a "view" that represents chars as bytes without doing any encoding.  So the byte buffer will contain the equivalent of UTF-16 (i.e. 2 bytes per character) without any BOM.